# the methods of live streaming from PC to HoloLens 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens

I want to stream real-time video from the PC's screen capture or the webcam connected on PC to the HoloLens 2. I have tried to use obs-studio to capture video on PC and use vlc to receive and play the stream on HoloLens 2. But the delay is more than two seconds. Are there some other more effective methods to achieve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular low latency video streaing methods result in subsecond latency. Effectively the end-to-end latency can be well under 100 ms, however this requires that you use proper mix of technologies including: screen capture, video codecs, hardware acceleraton, networking, Unity integration. The technologies you mentioned are far from optimal stack and hence the result you are observing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MR-WebRTC for that. Just follow the tuts [here](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can download screentask and follow the steps here, then open a browser on the hololens and tada! Your HL and PC must be on the same network.

I'm wondering though, how to include this streamed screen into a unity quad so I can incorporate it in my unity game for the HL or HL2.